# What's causing a JDBC datasource to not work on only one of three ColdFusion servers?

Tags: jdbc, coldfusion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, driver, datasource

I've established functional Snowflake JDBC datasources on two ColdFusion servers, and I'm able to successfully execute queries using these datasources. The same datasource configuration is not working on one other similarly configured server, however. When I submit the datasource details on that server, the error returned is: "Connection verification failed for data source: snowflake_jdbc
java.sql.SQLException: null."

Following are the environment details:

- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- ColdFusion 2021 Update 12
- Snowflake JDBC driver 3.14.4
- Java JDK 11.0.21 (64-bit)

Following are the datasource connection details I've entered in the ColdFusion admin page under Data & Services --> Data Sources:

- JDBC URL: `jdbc:snowflake://*ACCOUNT-IDENTIFIER*.snowflakecomputing.com/?JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT=json`
- Driver Class: `net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver`
- User name: `*USERNAME*`
- Password: `*PASSWORD*`

When I execute a query using this failed datasource, this is the "caused by" portion of the error stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.JDBCPool.createPhysicalConnection(JDBCPool.java:764) at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.ConnectionRunner$RunnableConnection.run(ConnectionRunner.java:67) ... 1 more
```

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag$DatabaseQueryException: Error Executing Database Query. at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.startQueryExecution(QueryTag.java:929) at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag(QueryTag.java:821) at cftestsnowflake2ecfm126401439.runPage(E:\Inetpub\wwwroot\applicationDirectory\testScript.cfm:4) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:257) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:749) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:578) at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:613) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:43) at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:162) at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45) at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:97) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:81) at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:60) at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:231) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:311) at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:170) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136) at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:46) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:47) at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136) at coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:57) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:47) at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:446) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.JDBCPool.createPhysicalConnection(JDBCPool.java:764) at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.ConnectionRunner$RunnableConnection.run(ConnectionRunner.java:67) ... 1 more
```

I've deleted and rebuilt the datasource, deleted and replaced the JDBC driver, rolled back the driver version from the latest, 3.14.4, to an earlier one mentioned in a forum post, 3.13.32. I've restarted the "ColdFusion 2021 Application Server" service after making changes such as the driver replacement and rollback.

This datasource on this server did briefly work for one afternoon, and I was able to run queries using it. Later that same afternoon, having changed nothing, I could no longer get it to work.

Full text of error after trying Snowflake sample Java program:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: 
        JDBC driver internal error: Error while reading config file at location: 
        E:\ColdFusion2021\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib\snowflake-jdbc-3.14.4.jar.
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.setClientConfig(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:130)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:107)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:85)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:206)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
        at SnowflakeJDBCExample.getConnection(SnowflakeJDBCExample.java:90)
        at SnowflakeJDBCExample.main(SnowflakeJDBCExample.java:31)
```

Comment: Is the 3rd server in the same network segment as the other two? Can you try [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd) to eliminate any network related errors?

Comment: One of the servers with the functioning datasource is Internet-facing. The other is internal, as is the server with the datasource that is not working. SnowCD returns "All checks passed" when I run it on the server with the non-functioning datasource.

Comment: What about trying a simple JDBC sample program like [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/jdbc/jdbc-using#java-sample-program) one to see if it works? The stacktrace shows nothing from JDBC side so I am wondering if this is not an issue only with ColdFusion.

Comment: I tried the sample program you linked to. On the servers where the datasource is currently working, the result was `Done creating JDBC connection`. On the server where the datasource is not working, the result was: `Exception in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver internal error: Error while reading config file at location: E:\ColdFusion2021\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib\snowflake-jdbc-3.14.4.jar.` I'll provide the full error text in my original post.

Comment: The stacktrace points to the fact JDBC cannot read/find the config file for logging. Have you added [client_config_file](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/jdbc/jdbc-parameters?client_config_file#client-config-file) parameter anywhere? Otherwise, can you try as a workaround to export the environment variable `SF_CLIENT_CONFIG_FILE` pointing it to a valid Windows path and a file called `sf_client_config.json` then add the following content to the file: `{"common":{"log_level":"error","log_path":"<SOME_PATH>/jdbc.log"}}`